# lstinputlisting adds cryptic line

Tags: latex, listings, lstlisting

i am using lstinputlisting in a latex document to include some source code. When I am giving a specific line range or firstline to start with there is a cryptic line added directly before my code looking like that:

[code line added by latex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AIjz.png)

My latex code:

```
\lstset{  % Konfiguration
xleftmargin=0.5cm,
language=C++,  % C++ als Sprache vordefinieren. Optional überschreiben
basicstyle=\small,
backgroundcolor=\color{lgray},
keywordstyle=\color{black}\bfseries,
commentstyle=\color{black}\small,
showstringspaces=false,
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\tiny,
numbersep=5pt,
breaklines=true,
tabsize=4,
showtabs=false,
}

\lstinputlisting[linerange=739-745]{Marlin/Configuration.h}
```

Does someone know where this line comes from and how to fix it?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
    \lstinputlisting[linerange={740-745}]{example.h}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: the problem only occurs when implementing code from another file but not when directly typing the code into the latex document. I don't know how to make a compilable example when it needs an external file.

Comment: Can you share a dummy .h test file which exhibits the same problem so we can reproduce the problem? You could try if you can reproduce with the `filecontents`environment, but it might be caused by the specific encoding of the file, so maybe shared it via github, dropbox or similar

Comment: Okay I figured out now it has to do something with my code file. If I short it down and delete everything besides the part of the code that I want to quote, the problem doesn't occur anymore.

Comment: So both the letters "ů" and "š" take part several times in the comments in my file before the part of the code I am using. If I delete them, the extra line is gone. Is there any other way by chance? I tried escaping it with literate = {š}{{\v{s}}}1
 {ů}{{\r{u}}}1 but that doesn't do anything here.

Comment: please add a reproducible example to your question

Comment: I had the same issue except with an empty line at the start of the listing. It was resolved when I took out the non-ascii characters from the inputted code file.